# How do I find URLs when I do not have the link

Tags: python, url, web-scraping

I am trying to **scrape** a website. Usually the new pages are available via a link on the front page. But sometimes, the pages are created but the link to the page is displayed on the front page with a delay.

So basically I know that the page does exist, but I cannot access it as I do not know the URL. Is there a way sto **scrape** a website to get the "hidden" URLs?

I am doing this using python but whichever language would do.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If _"with a delay"_ means the new page is not referred to _anywhere_ in the content available to you at this point, then of course you can't do this (other than making an attempt at "guessing" the new page URL.)

Comment: If you know the page is created why can’t you have its url ?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer the question.   How does the site implement this delay?   Is the URL programmatically created or is it fetched via an AJAX call by the site?